# Animate height of menu bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

What I really want is to have the same effect on the website of www.ditto.com by the menu, if anyone can figure that out, it would be really great, but if not this is what I have and please if anyone can answer this question, I'm in the middle of making a website for someone and I need this info fast!!

This code waits 0.8s when going up but it doesn't wait when it goes down, it just pops down.

Thanks in advance!!

You can see the full code here here: http://jsfiddle.net/zZPPR/

**CSS**

```
         .one
            {
                max-height: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
            }
            .two
            {
                max-height: 200px;
                 overflow:visible;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that target the second animation in the link. Still a draft though.

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/5/

Update: Max-height is causing speed issues, making the feeling the transition too fast or slow. Here is an alternative solution using transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/7/ same version with Chrome vendor prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/T4Nbk/9/

CSS:

```
ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul > li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

ul > li li
{
    display: block;
}

ul > li:before
{
    background-color:gray;
    top: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    z-index:-1;
}

ul > li a
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul > li ul
{
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-property: max-height;
}

ul > li:hover:before
{
    top:0;
}

ul > li:hover ul
{
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>News & Events</li>
            <li>
                Discover
                <ul>
                    <li>Jordan</li>
                    <li>Jordan</li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS of the solution using transforms:
Inspired by: [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto)

```
ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul > li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

ul > li li
{
    display: block;
}

ul > li:before
{
    background-color:gray;
    top: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    z-index:-1;
}

ul > li a
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul > li ul
{
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    transform-origin: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
}

ul > li:hover:before
{
    top:0;
}

ul > li:hover ul
{
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Comment: This is turning out GREAT!! Just one last thing, can you please make the same effect supported on other browsers?

Comment: here is a bug-fix: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/3/ have to use max-height. Should be pretty cross browser by now. There are no prefixes, but i don't think that will be required here.

Comment: for some reason when i put it in dreamweaver the effect doesn't work, but in chrome it does?

Comment: +1 @NicoO Good answer pal. It would be sweet if we were able to animate the height decreasing too.

Comment: Thank you @JackWilliams see updated answer. There is second fiddle linked that feels better: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/7/

Comment: if i add a background color to nav, the top menu dosn't turn grey on hover?

Comment: z-index issue. Just add links or spans to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/8/

Comment: There is a problem with the  jsfiddle.net/NicoO/T4Nbk/8 code. The "Jordan" is displayed before hovered?

Comment: The 1st time was good, idk what changed?  Also is it possible to add another <li> to "jordan"?

Comment: i mean, you can wait more than 8 minutes ... Last fix: http://jsfiddle.net/T4Nbk/9/ vendor prefix for chrome. the rest can be figured out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49855/discussion-between-user2356557-and-nico-o)

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that you're not transitioning the `overflow` property. So as soon as the class `two` is applied, the overflow is set to visible and the content shows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow:visible` from the class `.two` and it will work

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zZPPR/10/)

Comment: You can probably increase the time from `0.8s` to  a larger value in `.two` for a smoother transition

Comment: ur not right.  if i add the "smooth" transition to the .two, nothing happens.

Comment: how are you adding the "smooth" transition?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove overflow:visible;